# Which should we use to get Publication ID- TcmUri.ContextRepositoryId or TcmUri.PublicationId

Tags: 2013, content-manager

I was wondering that we have two properties in `TcmUri` class - `ContextRepositoryId` and `PublicationId` both of these supposedly gives us the Publication ID from a TCM URI passed in the constructor and in most of the scenario gives same result.

If I google, then everywhere it is recommended to use the `TcmUri.PublicationId` if we would like to retrieve the  Publication ID from a TCM URI whereas the `TcmUri.ContextRepositoryID` is more precise as compared to the `TcmUri.PublicationId`

My questions:

- Any rational behind having these two properties
- Is it OK to use `TcmUri.ContextRepositoryID` in all scenario as `TcmUri.PublicationId` would fail if TCM URI of a publication is passed to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of a Repository was introduced with the .NET implementation of Tridion (so 5.3 I should think). .NET allowed for a class hierarchy, as opposed to the strictly interface-based approach of COM. Until then, and indeed, until now, the only kind of Repository in Tridion is a Publication.

The Context Repository of an item is a BluePrinting concept. It's the repository in which you have accessed the item. So if I open an item called tcm:5-1234, its context repository will be 5. If it's not really there, and only a shared item that lives in a different place in the blueprint, it's Owning Repository could be different. So if my component is shared from publication 3, its Owning repository would be 3.

So as things stand now, the Context Repository of an item will always be its Publication. If there were ever to be another kind of repository, then presumably items in it wouldn't have a Publication, while the Context Repository would be expected to be available. (An item has to live somewhere, right? Obviously, System items live in their own special place.)

So if you're writing code that deals with publications specifically, you might use Publication.Id. In general, though, most often when you need to know what the repository/publication is, you are doing something with BluePrinting. Although we often talk of Publications when dealing with BluePrinting, it's actually Repositories that do BluePrinting; Publications just inherit this behaviour, so for BluePrinting work, use the Repository.

Comment: perfect answer Dom; this clarifies the thing

Answer (score 2):

The main difference I can see - value of this properties for SystemWideObjects:

```
 publication.Id = tcm:0-4-1
 publication.Id.PublicationId = -1
 publication.Id.ContextRepositoryId = 4
 approvalStatus.Id = tcm:0-2-131073
 approvalStatus.Id.PublicationId = -1
 approvalStatus.Id.ContextRepositoryId = 0
```

So: For RepositoryLocalObjects there is no difference. For SystemWideObjects properties have different behavior: publicationId is always -1, ContextRepositoryId returns exact the publication value of the item.

Comment: So that is my question - what is the significance of publicationId property when ContextRepositoryId can be used in all scenarios